# Insert empty rows in select result if number of rows is under a certain amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue with a report i need to build for a customer with Crystal Report 2016. I must build a select in MSSQL where it may return up to 10 rows. But here is the problem, when less than 10 results are returned, i still need to have 10 rows. So I were thinking add empty values to specific columns, but can't find any useful information in the documentation. Been told that can be achieved using a stored procedure, but my company is not allowed to add anything to the customer's database.

Beside stored procedures, is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Use a CTE to produce 10 fake rows, use UNION ALL to combine the actual resultset with the 10 fake rows, and then select the top 10 using an appropriate SORT BY clause. Tag CR (why did you not?) and perhaps a CR expert will reply with a better approach based on available functionality.

Comment: Create empty sections in the Crystal report with blank textboxes. Conditionally suppress them based on tbe count of rows returned.

Comment: It seems like CR used to collapse empty areas so possibly the empty textboxes are overkill. But this is appropriately handled in the presentation rather than the query.

Comment: shawnt00, problem is that the empty rows boxes still need to be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create a "numbers table" as either a CTE or derived table, for numbers 1-10, and then make sure that your query has some kind of line number. Then just LEFT OUTER JOIN to your query.

Something like this:

```
WITH NUMBERS AS
(
SELECT 1 LINE
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT 6
UNION ALL
SELECT 7
UNION ALL
SELECT 8
UNION ALL
SELECT 9
UNION ALL
SELECT 10
)

SELECT YOURTABLE.* 
    FROM NUMBERS
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YOURTABLE
            ON YOURTABLE.LINE = NUMBERS.LINE
```

There might be something slightly more elegant but that should work...

Comment: I changed the YOURTABLE with a subquery and added a ROW_NUMBER() to generate the link to NUMBERS