# How to add rows to a specific number multiple times in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I already asked for help on a part of my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69409924/insert-empty-rows-in-select-result-if-number-of-rows-is-under-a-certain-amount).

I used to get 10 rows no matter if there are filled or not. But now I'm facing something else where I need to do it multiple times in the same query result.

```
WITH NUMBERS AS
(
    SELECT 1 rowNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10
)
SELECT DISTINCT sp.SLC_ID, c.rowNumber, c.PCE_ID
FROM SELECT_PART sp
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.*
    FROM NUMBERS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT a.*
        FROM (
            SELECT SELECT_PART.SLC_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SELECT_PART.SLC_ID) as 
            rowNumber, SELECT_PART.PCE_ID
            FROM SELECT_PART
            WHERE SELECT_PART.SLC_ID = (must be the same as sp.SLC_ID and can''t hardcode it)
        ) a
    ) b
    ON b.rowNumber = NUMBERS.rowNumber
) c ON c.SLC_ID = sp.SLC_ID
ORDER BY sp.SLC_ID, c.rowNumber
```

It works fine for the first 10 lines, but next SLC_ID only got 1 empty line

I need it to be like that

```
SLC_ID    rowNumer    PCE_ID
1         1           0001
1         2           0002
1         3           NULL
1         ...         ...
1         10          NULL
2         1           0011
2         2           0012
2         3           0013
2         ...         ...
2         10          0020
3         1           0021
3         ...         ...
```

Really need it that way to build a report.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually building a query-specific number list where you have to include every possible number you need (1 through 10 in this case), create a numbers table.

```
DECLARE @UpperBound INT = 1000000;

;WITH cteN(Number) AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) - 1
  FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
)
SELECT [Number] INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM cteN WHERE [Number] <= @UpperBound;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_Number ON dbo.Numbers([Number])
WITH 
(
  FILLFACTOR = 100,      -- in the event server default has been changed
  DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW -- if Enterprise & table large enough to matter
);
```

[Source: mssqltips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/)

Alternatively, since you can't add data, use a table that already exists in SQL Server.

```
WITH NUMBERS AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT Number as rowNumber FROM master..spt_values where type = 'P'
)
SELECT DISTINCT sp.SLC_ID, c.rowNumber, c.PCE_ID
FROM SELECT_PART sp
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT b.*
    FROM NUMBERS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT a.*
        FROM(
            SELECT SELECT_PART.SLC_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SELECT_PART.SLC_ID) as 
            rowNumber, SELECT_PART.PCE_ID
            FROM SELECT_PART
            WHERE SELECT_PART.SLC_ID = (must be the same as sp.SLC_ID and can''t hardcode it)
        ) a
    ) b
    ON b.rowNumber = NUMBERS.rowNumber
) c ON c.SLC_ID = sp.SLC_ID
ORDER BY sp.SLC_ID, c.rowNumber
```

NOTE: Max value for this solution is 2047

Comment: I cannot change the database structure. I'm not allowed to create index or tables even for temporary storage of data

Comment: @EricBrochu Change the `10` to a `0`, and you can use CROSS JOIN from your existing `NUMBERS` CTE to itself multiple times to quickly generate an arbitrarily large set of numbers on the fly.

Comment: @EricBrochu, instead, can you do `WITH NUMBERS AS (SELECT DISTINCT number from master..spt_values where type = 'P')`?